# Sklearn - predict_proba equivalents

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

So some of the models in Sci-kit learn such as Logistic Regression support the predict_proba method which I use heavily. Is there an other way for models such as Lasso to output a similar probability array, since they don't support predict_proba?

Also: I'm working with a three outcome dataset where the probabilities between the outcomes can be relatively even - any general suggestions for models/tunings to try to improve probability precision, that can handle 50+ feature columns? =)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sklearn introduced [Probability calibration](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/calibration.html) exactly for this purpose. Improving or adding support for classifiers without a natural probability-output.

There is also a [blog-post](https://jmetzen.github.io/2015-04-14/calibration.html) about this.

Usage will be based on [CalibratedClassifierCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.calibration.CalibratedClassifierCV.html#sklearn.calibration.CalibratedClassifierCV).

Of those two methods, *sigmoid* and *isotonic*, the former is quite popular as the underlying method behind libsvm's probability-output, which you can see in sklearn's wrapper [SVC](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html)